# Convert numpy array full of time deltas to hours

Tags: python, numpy, timedelta

I have a numpy array full of timedeltas I want to be able to convert them to hours.

```
print(times_arr)

array([datetime.timedelta(seconds=28800),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=30600),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=23400),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=27000),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=23400),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=23400),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=30600),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=23400),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=27000),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=23400),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=30600),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=27000),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=23400),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=23400),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=30600),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=28800),
       datetime.timedelta(seconds=23400)])
```

Does anyone know how I can convert this array to hours so array[(8, 8.56 etc..

I have tried everything I know how. I am new to python. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Convert to `timedelta64[m]` dtype, then go from there:

```
arr.astype('timedelta64[m]').astype(int) / 60
# array([8. , 8.5, 6.5, 7.5, 6.5, 6.5, 8.5, 6.5, 7.5, 6.5, 8.5, 7.5, 6.5,
#        6.5, 8.5, 8. , 6.5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `arr.astype('timedelta64[s]').astype("int64")/3600` instead of `arr.astype('timedelta64[m]').astype(int) / 60` which will cause "loss" of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the total seconds in each timedelta by 3600 to get your desired output.

```
new = np.array([delta.total_seconds() / 3600 for delta in times_array])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
print(datetime.strptime(str(timedelta(seconds=30600)),'%H:%M:%S').strftime('%H.%M'))

08.30
```